# How to obtain a subset of records within a context using EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework

A newbie question. I am using EntityFramework 4.0. The backend database has a function that will return a subset of records based on time.

Example of working code is:

```
  var query = from rx in context.GetRxByDate(tencounter,groupid)
               select rx;

  var result = context.CreateDetachedCopy(query.ToList());
  return result;
```

I need to verify that a record does not exist in the database before inserting a new record. Before performing the "Any" filter, I would like to populate the context.Rxes with a subset of the larger backend database using the above "GetRxByDate()" function.

I do not know how to populate "Rxes" before performing any further filtering since Rxes is defined as

```
IQueryable<Rx> Rxes
```

and does not allow "Rxes =.. ". Here is what I have so far:

```
using (var context = new EnityFramework())
{
   if (!context.Rxes.Any(c =>  c.Cform == rx.Cform ))
   {
      // Insert new record
         Rx r = new Rx();
         r.Trx = realtime;

         context.Add(r);
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
 }
```

I am fully prepared to kick myself since I am sure the answer is simple.

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

If I do it this way, "Any" seems to return the opposite results of what is expected:

```
var g = context.GetRxByDate(tencounter, groupid).ToList();
```

if( g.Any(c => c.Cform == rx.Cform ) {....}

Comment: I think you shouldn't do such things in the context, but in a service class. A context should just return clean `DbSet`s and not contain any business logic.

Comment: @GertArnold An example would be great.

Comment: Ok. Problem solved as shows in the Edit to the question. However, I am using Telerik OpenAccess to generate the EntityFramework domain and "Any" is buggy. Need to replace it with Count() > 0.

Comment: Wrong. Problem not solved. Count() with && in predicate also fails on Telerik OpenAccess.  What to do?